# Attaching SQLite database to an application

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data

My application is supposed to use SQLite database, which I want to plug into the application. The sqlite file is located directly in the application folder (you can see in the screenshot). If I add the full path in the line `let storeUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath:FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath).appendingPathComponent("/Users/nm/App/Songbook/Model.sqlite")` then the application reads the data from the database. But if I type only Model.sqlite, the application does not read. I can not leave it like this in the final version of the application. Please suggest what I am doing wrong. Below is the full code.

```
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
        let storeUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath).appendingPathComponent("/Users/nm/App/Spiewnik/Spiewnik/Model.sqlite")
        
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeUrl)]
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXqdw.png)

**UPDATA:**
My code now looks like this and in the simulator everything works. However, on the phone the database is empty.

```
    static let shared = PersistenceController()
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
        let dbName = "Model.sqlite"
        let dbUrl = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(dbName)
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dbUrl.path) {
            //move the file
            do {
                if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Model", withExtension: "sqlite"){
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: fileURL, to: dbUrl)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: dbUrl)]
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
```

```
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask) //or .libraryDirectory
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you print `storeUrl`? My suspicion is that it isn't where you think it is. You should be copying the file from your bundle into the application directory or library before using it -- not using `currentDirectoryPath`. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: If it passes only Model.sqlite it print URL:  file:///Model.sqlite. As for the second issue, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Maybe he'll describe what effect he wants to achieve overall. I want the application at the start to have added data therefore which includes the "completed" database. Perhaps there are other ways for such cases.

Comment: Why don't you simply create an SQLite table programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to load your database from your app's bundle, which is going to be problematic because bundle files aren't writable. Instead, you need to copy it to a location you'll have read/write access to. One possibility is the application's documents directory (or library directory, which is common on macOS).

First, you'll want to be able to get the URL for that directory:

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask) //or .libraryDirectory
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

Then, check to see if the database exists there already. If not, copy your bundle file:

```
let dbName = "Model.sqlite"
let dbUrl = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(dbName)
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dbUrl.path) {
    //move the file
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Model", withExtension: "sqlite")!, to: dbUrl)
    } catch {
        print(error)
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

//load your database from dbUrl here
```

Then, you can use `dbUrl` and load your database from the file that you've now copied over.

Comment: I have done as you suggested and in the simulator the data is retrieved from this database. However, if I run the application on the phone, there is no data.

Comment: Did you use the documents or library directory?

Comment: I use the catalog documents.

Comment: There must be another variable at play. Have you tried completely deleting the app from the phone and reinstalling? Have you used the debugger to see if the file copying the model over is getting called?

Comment: That's how I tried to completely uninstall the apps on my phone. This did not have any effect. The copy procedure is called. However, I noticed that the database that is in xcappdata is empty.

Comment: That's as much as I can debug from here unless you can provide a project to recreate it.

Comment: A different path is passed in the dbUrl parameter on the phone and a different one in the simulator. Phone: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D81FAA66-4293-4154-94FC-289C56A583AF/Documents/Model.sqlite"  Simulator: "file:///Users/nm/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/999FF12A-0323-49F1-B8E6-D25443353EC4/data/Containers/Data/Application/24C42248-0A9E-475E-9C10-3ED52351A7C9/Documents/Model.sqlite" Apparently the database that is copied on the phone is empty for some reason. I wonder if I put the code buying data in the right place.

Comment: Yes, that'd be expected as the locations in the filesystem wouldn't be the same. But, without knowing what they are, it's hard to say if they are erroneous.

Comment: I have downloaded via Xcode "Xcode Application Data Package", After opening the package the database Model.sqlite which is in the documents directory is empty.

Comment: Try uninstalling and stopping the program before the `container.loadPersistentStores` runs -- see if the database is empty *right after* the copy takes place.

Comment: The problem is generated by this condition: `if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Model", withExtension: "sqlite")` It is not satisfied and copying is not performed.

Comment: If I remove this condition, an error occurs: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Okay, that's a pretty clear error. It can't find Model.sqlite in your bundle. Are you positive that that file is in the "Copy bundle resources" list for your app? Are you sure that the file name matches exactly (including case sensitivity)?

Comment: Ok, it was not in the "Copy Package Resources" list.